# QML: how to distribute equably in RowAlignment?

Tags: qt, qml

I have the QML code below:

```
RowLayout {
    anchors.fill: parent
    spacing: 2

    Rectangle {
        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignCenter
        Layout.preferredWidth: 60
        Layout.preferredHeight: 60

        color: "red"
    }

    Rectangle {
        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignCenter
        Layout.preferredWidth: 60
        Layout.preferredHeight: 60

        color: "green"
    }
```

And I receive distribution like this:

[image: <-->RECT<--><-->RECT<-->]

But I would like to have another distribution:

[image: <--->RECT<--->RECT<--->]

How can I do this? Ideally without JS.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not as nice as one would like to see, but this does the trick for me:

```
RowLayout {
    anchors.fill: parent
    spacing: 0

    Item {
        Layout.fillWidth: true
    }

    Rectangle {
        Layout.preferredWidth: 60
        Layout.preferredHeight: 60

        color: "red"
    }

    Item {
        Layout.fillWidth: true
    }

    Rectangle {
        Layout.preferredWidth: 60
        Layout.preferredHeight: 60

        color: "green"
    }

    Item {
        Layout.fillWidth: true
    }
}
```